# hibernate: change a bean field and then issue a query, query sees changed field

Tags: hibernate

I am confused about the behavior of hibernate bean setters within a Session.  I thought that when you set a bean field in a session, hibernate just knows that the bean is dirty, and on session close, this is a pending update, which will be flushed to the database.

However, I ran a test within one hibernate session where I fetched a bean by its id, changed a field from true to false, and then did an HQL query for a list of all such beans where this field was false.  The "dirty" bean showed up in the result set as if hibernate had already made a database UPDATE when I called the setter.  Then I did a session.clear() before leaving the session, to cancel pending updates and evict all beans.  I assumed that this would effectively throw away the dirty changes of the setter calls.  Yet I checked the database and the change from true to false was recorded.  NOTE: never called session.flush() inside this session.

It seems that Hibernate must be issuing a database UPDATE call as soon as I call a bean setter.  But this doesn't seem right?

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, Hibernate flushes any pending changes before querying (if it decides that pending change may affect query result). If you don't want to save any changes to DB, you have to rollback the transaction. If you call `clear()` but commit the transaction, it will be persisted in DB, because `clear()` is invoked too late (after SQL UPDATE). Or change flush mode as suggested by kamlesh, but make sure you know what you are doing while choosing a particular flush mode.

PS: Welcome to Hibernate world. Expect more such surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the session FlushMode of hibernate.
If its an **Always** or **Auto** mode , then hibernate will flush the dirty data into database, before executing new query.

[java doc for FlushMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html)